# Which expression is more common and defining for LaTeX commands - command or macro?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've seen many questions using the word *command* or *commands*. There are also questions writing *macro* or *macros*. Regarding tagging, which should be the master and which the synonym mapped to it? Until now, the tag [macros] is widely used. But it won't be a problem to merge it with [commands] if we desire. Or do you think, those terms may be separated?

Pro [commands]:

- searching for ["commands"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commands) gives 19 pages, searching for ["macros"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=macros) just 2. The latter is a result of the "macros" tag. (The search feature switches to [tag search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) automatically.)
- http://www.google.de/search?q=LaTeX+commands gives 3.100.000 results, http://www.google.de/search?q=LaTeX+macros gives 251.000.
- LaTeX *is* a macro language. Does [macros] tell anything specific? Though we could distinguish between commands, environments, lengths, counters, ifs and more. I prefer to have [commands], [environments], [lengts] and so on.
- For questions or searches regarding `\newcommand`, `\providecommand`, `\renewcommand`, the number of arguments, starred forms and so on I believe the conceptual tag [commands] would seem more natural than [macros].

I don't wish to make a great fuss about just one tag, though commands and macros are a very basic concept and I'm interested in opinions.

If you agree, please vote the question up or tell it by a comment or an anwer.

If you disagree, please tell it in an answer (or comment) which may be voted up.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be likely that new users add a `commands` tag to just about every question?

Comment: Since you're proposing a definite change to the site, I think the [feature-request] tag would be appropriate here.

Comment: @Charles: this concerns just tagging, no feature. I though at first, you mean the questions regarding commands and environments and if we introcuce a visual sign in tags (backslash or curly braces).

Comment: @Caramdir: avoiding this by using `macros` instead of `commands` is a bit 'security through obscurity' ;-) But you're right, adding `commands` (but also `macros`) (to not general commands-related questions) might be tempting.

Comment: @Stefan: Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request - on meta.SO, use of [feature-request] and [retag-request] is used to build support for complex or controversial changes to tags.  A point for using [feature-request], even though moderators might not be needed to make the change happen, is that it signals that voting is supporting or opposing the idea, rather than saying the idea is worth discussing.

Comment: Somebody seems to have created the [`custom-command`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-command) tag. Should that be [merged](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/macros/synonyms)?

Comment: Yes, I merged it.

Answer (score 5):

For me, a `macros` tag would imply that the submitter has a question regarding a custom `\newcommand` that he\she is constructing, and it doesn't work as expected (does that happen often?). Otherwise, if said user has problems with an "official" command from widely available third-party package, a `commands` tag would seem more natural.

So, I think `macros` should stay, but its intended use should be clear.

Comment: In that case the `commands` tag is about as superfluous as the `latex` tag.

Comment: You're right, of course. Apparently I haven't paid enough attention to what Stefan said.

Comment: So, \\*command commands might imply the tag `macros`, not `commands`. :-D Well, such general tags might be confusing. But introducing `macro-definition` wouldn't be of much help. But we will see. At least here's a place to talk about.

Answer (score 5):

Two points of programming language terminology:

1. Not all commands are macros: `\input` is a command, but as a Tex primitive, it is not a macro.
2. Not all macro uses are command invocations: you can assign contents to macros, and use them with `\ifx` conditionals without ever expanding them.

The second seems a rather thin point: macro expansions are (potentially imperative) command executions, and `\ifx` can be seen as an introspective equality test.

So, commands are macros plus primitives.  And so the case is strengthened that [macros] should be a synonym for [commands].

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer by user Sašo Živanović to my question "What is “plain TeX”?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97537/14996), a **command** can be a **primitive** (from "virgin TeX") or a **macro**.

Answer (score 2):

How about `[command-creation]` or something similar that contains “command“ but is more specific than `[commands]`?